# HTML/CSS multiple columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out the best way to create this:
[image]

The black square represents small icons, and there is heading and paragraph of that certain section. The icons should be aligned to the heading. The paragraph should be just underneath the heading.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can simply use pure css to do that...

Comment: You can use bootstrap columns to get the 3 column per row structure.

Comment: Flexbox, but the paragraph is not aligned under heading..it is just under

Comment: Show us your code please, then we can help you

Comment: Bootstrap would be a nice solution indeed.. its up to you ! it may be a bit complicated for nothing but then would help you design the rest of your website easily aswell

Comment: Flexbox is a good solution here, you say you've used it but what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please do not ask us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use absolute positioned icons with a negative margin and float for the 3 columns with a width of 33.33%.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><img src="" /><h2>Heading</h2><p>Paragraph</p></div>
  <div class="col"><img src="" /><h2>Heading</h2><p>Paragraph</p></div>
  <div class="col"><img src="" /><h2>Heading</h2><p>Paragraph</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.row {overflow: auto;}
.col {width: 33.33%; float: left; padding-left: 100px;}
.col img {position: absolute; width: 80px; margin-left: -100px;}

@media (max-width: 991px) {.col {width: 100%;}}
```

Here a working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqBNeL

Comment: Please suggest flexbox here... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just displaying icons, I would not use an image tag at all as they are not "content" per-se. I'd be using background images.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;

  /*Adjust the below lines based on your icon size*/
  padding-left: 55px;
  width: calc(33% - 55px);
  
}

h2 {
  /*Adjust the below lines based on your icon size and aligning requirements*/
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.bill {
  background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/50/50);
}

.city {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-50-50-7.jpg);
}

.cat {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-50-50-7.jpg);
}

.food {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-50-50-7.jpg);
}

.sports {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-50-50-7.jpg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bill">
    <h2>Bill Murray</h2>
    <p>Some Para</p>
  </li>
  <li class="city">
    <h2>City</h2>
    <p>Some Para</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h2>Cat</h2>
    <p>Some Para</p>
  </li>
  <li class="food">
    <h2>F00d</h2>
    <p>Some Para</p>
  </li>
  <li class="sports">
    <h2>Sports</h2>
    <p>Some Para</p>
  </li>
  <li class="bill">
    <h2>Bill Murray</h2>
    <p>Some Para</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h2>Cat</h2>
    <p>Some Para</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```